# How to set the value of a background Image in Vue using a URL generated by an API

Tags: javascript, css, api, vue.js, background

I am trying to set the value of the background image of my #app element in Vue to the response that is generated from Unsplash's API. I am able to retrieve the image URL, but I am having some difficulty in trying to relay that information to the background style element.

Overall, my goal is to use a random image and display it on the screen every page reload.

My method:

1. I pulled down the URL from the Unsplash API in the methods section
2. I then created an image in the data section and set that equal to the response containing the URL
3. Finally, I set the style attribute in the template section to :style="image"

This has not been working for me. I thought of using computed properties, but I wasn't even sure where to start there.

Additionally, since I have a linear gradient on the background property, would altering the image part effectively delete the linear gradient part on the background property?

If you can provide any assistance that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Below, I have provided my app.vue file

```html
<template>
  <div id="app" :style="image">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      image: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    renderImage: function() {
      axios
        .get(
          'https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/?client_id=MY_KEY'
        )
        .then(response => {
          console.log([response.data, response.data.location.title])
          this.image = response.data.urls.full
        })
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.renderImage()
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">

#app {
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(245, 246, 252, 0) 45%,
      rgb(0, 0, 0) 100%
    )
    no-repeat center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the syntax in the Vue [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html), try this

```html
<template>
 ....
  <div id="app" :style="imageStyleObject">
....
</template>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    image: '',
  }
},
computed: { // will be re-computed when the image property changes
  imageStyleObject() {
    return {
      backgroundImage: `url(${this.image})`...
      // insert other styles
    }
  }
}
```

Regarding the second part of the question, No, I see no reason why the linear gradient should be affected.

Comment: I looked into what you provided and I have one clarification and one question. First, doesn't background-image need to be camel case because it is being used in javascript? Second, I got an error or url is not defined. Do I need to put quotes around url(this.image)'?

Comment: You are absolutely right, @TylerMorales. I have updated the answer. I put a backtick on the url and I think it should work now.

Comment: Yes, it did. The only issue I had was with the order of the image and gradient. It seems like the the linear gradient needs to come before the image for the gradient and image to appear. With that figured out, everything is working great.

Comment: That’s great to hear. I am happy to have helped. Please accept my answer @tylermorales

Comment: Thanks. For the benefit of anyone who stumbles on the page, how did you solve the linear-gradient issue? @tylermorales

Comment: Very simply, to add a linear gradient on top of a background image, you must place the linear-gradient attribute before the image url. For example: backgroundImage: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, red), url(https://exampleURL.com). Keep in mind that this is the syntax for css in js and if you wanted to write it in css, you would have to use kabob casing the comma after ...red) is not necessary.